# Extracting users from twitter status in R. Non-trivial cases like RT@user @user:

Tags: regex, r, grepl

I want to extract usernames from a tweet where these usernames may be:

- followed by some non-alphanumerical characters.
- not preceded by a white space.

For instance, from this:

```
"RT@user1: This is a retweet that mentions @user2."
```

I would like to get a vector like

```
[1] @user1 @user2
```

(with or without the "@")

This is my current script:

```
    text <- "RT@user1: This is a retweet that mentions @user2."
    tokens <- unlist(strsplit(text, " "))
    mentions.mask <- grepl("@\\w+", tokens)
    mentions <- tokens[mentions.mask]
    cat(mentions)
    [1] "RT@user1:" "@user2."
```

How can I do it properly?

Comment: Can you put sample input and your expected output?

Comment: @Fede the sample input would be the `text` variable and the output  a vector containing `@user1` and  `@user2` Isn't it clear in my question?

Comment: I edited just in case.

Comment: it's clear now. I don't see anything wrong but missing capturing groups

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood it well, this seems pretty straightforward and your regex is just missing capturing groups. You can use this regex:

```
(@\w+)
^----^--- Note capturing groups
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/dD8gT8/1)**

In R you could use:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract("RT@user1: This is a retweet that mentions @user2.", "@\\w+")
```

Comment: Thanks @Fede. The thing is how to apply this to R. Regular expressions seems a bit different. For instance, something like `grep("@\\w+", text, value=TRUE)` only detects whether the pattern was found.

Comment: Perfect now! Just note it should be `str_extract_all` to get all the matches

Answer (score 2):

You could simply stick to using base R for this.

```
text <- "RT@user1: This is a retweet that mentions @user2."
regmatches(text, gregexpr('@\\w+', text))[[1]]
# [1] "@user1" "@user2"
```

Without the preceding `@`:

```
regmatches(text, gregexpr('@\\K\\w+', text, perl=T))[[1]]
# [1] "user1" "user2"
```